# How to get FreeRTOS on MSP430 using CCE?

Tags: msp430, freertos

I'd like to get FreeRTOS running on an MSP430 processor using Code Composer Essentials v3.1.  I found an example of just this at http://www.westmorelandengineering.com/toc.htm.  Specifically I’m working with FreeRTOS_Demo.zip, the top one.  When I try to open it with CCE I get an error that the workspace "was not created by this version of Code Composer".  So I tried to import the project and I get an error "The Managed Make project could not be read because of the following error: Project type com.ti.ccstudio.managedbuild.ui.programTargetID not found.  Managed Make functionality will not be available for this project."

I’m wondering what my problem is and how I can get the project to build, or should I go about this a different way?

Answer (score 4):

FreeRTOS support many, many, many chips and many, many, many compilers.  Anything that is not standard C code is kept in a port layer.

The next FreeRTOS release (V7, out in the next couple of weeks and already available in the SVN repository) includes a CCS4 port and demo for the MSP430F5438 (MSP430X core).

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I was told that TI's CCS compiler suite (used in CCE/CCS) will not build the FreeRTOS sources because the FreeRTOS sources include stuff written in gnu assembler syntax (file extension .s is common between CCS asm and Gnu asm, but syntax is not the same).  Until FreeRTOS is "ported" to the CCS compiler suite, your best bet is to use the full CCS with the GCC compiler instead of the CCS compiler.

Comment: By the way, why not email the folks at Westmorelandengineering?

Answer (score 0):

reviving a zombie thread...  not sure if CCE is even relevant now... you can get CCS 5.3 with code-size limited free MSP430 support.

I recently ported FreeRTOS to the CC430 using the new MP430Ware driver library from TI and Code Composer Studio 5.3, get it here:

http://www.freertos.org/Interactive_Frames/Open_Frames.html?http://interactive.freertos.org/entries/22894958-cc430f5137-ccs-5-3